# How to Make Java Recognize A Zero

Tags: java, double, zero

The title says it all. Right now if I input a number like 100.50, in my program it prints as 100.5. Is there an easy way to make the program recognize the zero?

Comment: It's the same number. What you want is string handling (i.e. representations of numbers). You would need to describe in more detail what you want - do you want to keep the input representation, or always format to two decimal digits, or...?

Comment: If I recall, you capitalize the first letter of each word in a title, correct? Thanks for the input but GAVD answered my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this trick.

```
String s = String.format("%.2f", 100.50);
```

Comment: That will do it thanks

Comment: Ill accept it in 8 minutes